# How do I convert this value into a datetime value I can understand in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write report in SQL for a ticket database and i need to filter on the date and time.

Unfortunately the values in the date time fields dont make sense to me.

How can I convert `1473140017153` to a `datetime` value?

Here are the strings and the dates and time that correspond to them.

```
1473140017153  06/09/2016 07:33 AM 
1473140228660  06/09/2016 07:37 AM
```

Comment: which dbms are u workinhg on

Comment: Are you looking to convert in a program, or within SQL itself. What is the value itself supposed to represent? It's not a unix timestamp

Comment: How do you know that `1473140017153`  means `06/09/2016 07:33 AM` if it doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: Seems to be unix time in millisecond.

Comment: Its SQL Server.

Comment: This is the database for a ticketing system. I compared the string in the DB to what is displayed for the same ticket on the GUI for COMPLETEDTIME

Comment: I need to convert in SQL itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have no clue what RDBMS you are using, forcing us to basically give you answers for all possibilities:

**SQL Server:**

```
DATEADD(ms, col, '19700101')
```

or

```
DATEADD(s, col / 1000, '19700101')
```

**Oracle:**

```
TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(col / 1000, 'SECOND')
```

**MySQL:**

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(col / 1000)
```

**Postgres:**

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(col / 1000)
```

If you're using SQLite, you're out of luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is in SQL Server. I have tried DATEADD(ms, wo.COMPLETEDTIME, '19700101') as 'date'. however i get the following error. Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: Use `DATEADD(ms, col, '19700101')`, where `col` is the column containing your milliseconds since epoch data.

Comment: I get this error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Comment: Try using `DATEADD(s, wo.COMPLETEDTIME / 1000, '19700101')` ... the values you were feeding into `DATEADD` exceed the range for integers, this is the source of that error.

Comment: Ah! That works. however the time does not match the time in the GUI for the completed time of the same ticket.

Comment: select
wo.COMPLETEDTIME,
DATEADD(s, wo.COMPLETEDTIME / 1000, '19700101') as 'date'
from WorkOrder wo
left join WorkOrderStates wos on wos.workorderid = wo.workorderid
where wo.workorderid = '25303'

Comment: COMPLETEDTIME  date                 
-------------  -------------------  
1473140228660  2016-09-06 05:37:08

Comment: The time on the ticket GUI is: 06/09/2016 07:37 AM

Comment: @RenierSchutte This is probably a time zone issue.  The date you are getting back in GMT (London), and your data is probably two hours ahead (Germany?).  If you know how to correct, you can just add/subtract this amount of time as you convert.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the correct date and time using the following.

```
DATEADD(hh,2,DATEADD(s, wo.COMPLETEDTIME / 1000, '19700101')) as 'date'
```